# MySQL insert with autogenerated column in subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

I'm in the process of importing data from one table to another with a completely different schema. I can import the data from one column to another just fine, but there is an autogenerated column that gets set when a new row is inserted. The code just does a count()+100001 on the table, which I'm trying to replicate in a query but I'm having issues.

Here's my query:

```
insert into prospect(pid,pfirst,plast,paddress,pcity,pstate,pzip,eid,pdate,pnum,pprim)
  select custid,cfirst,clast,street,city,state,zip,csrid,lastvisit,
     (select count(pid)+100000 from prospect),celphone from customer limit 140000,1000;
```

The pnum column (the generated one) should be 100000, 100001, 100002, etc, but they all being end up 100000. I assume it's because I'm only doing a single insert, so the count() is 0 the whole way through.

How would I accomplish what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select count(pid) into @auto from prospect;
insert into prospect(pid,pfirst,plast,paddress,pcity,pstate,pzip,eid,pdate,pnum,pprim) 
select custid,cfirst,clast,street,city,state,zip,csrid,lastvisit,
     @auto:=@auto+1,celphone from customer limit 140000,1000;
```

Change the value of **@auto** variable as per your need in first select statement.

Comment: Had to set it to start at 100000, but that worked out great. Thanks!